# How can a single point "b" be mapped to $0\times [-1,1]$?

Tags: general-topology, functions, proof-verification, connectedness, path-connected

I've  easily shown that **Topologist's Sine Curve(TSC)** is connected.Now I'm trying to fill the gaps in the following  proof  of **"showing TSC is not path-connected"** .While going through this proof i got some questions,i was unable to answer .

Suppose there is a path $f:[a,c]\rightarrow \bar S,$ from $(0,0)$ to (1,0) in the **Topologist's Sine Curve(TSC)**.

Consider the set of those $t$ for which $f(t)\in 0\times [-1,1]$ is closed,let this set be $K$.So,K is closed(K contains all of its limit points).So, K has a  largest element '**b**'(say) **({1})**.( **check the arguments in  this paragraph,if there is some scope of improvement please let me know** )

Then $f:$[**b**,$c$]$\rightarrow \bar S$ is a path  that maps **b** into the vertical interval {$0$}$\times [-1,1]$ and maps other  points of [b,c] to points of $S$.**({2},{3})**

We relabel the domain as $[0,1]$ for convenience.

let $f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, where $y(t)=\sin({\frac{1}{x(t)}})$

As $f$ is continuous,the coordinates $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are continuous as well.

We produce  a sequence   $<t_n>\rightarrow 0$ in $[0,1]$ such that $y(t_n)\not\to y(0)$,which violates the sequential criteria for convergence in Metric spaces.

Since,$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \bar S$ is a path.

So,$f(0)=x(0)$  and $f(t)=y(t)$ for $t>0$.

But,$f(0)=0$,So,$x(0)=0$ and $f(t)=y(t)$ for $t>0$.

Now,$x(0)=0$ and $y(t)=\sin (\frac{1}{x(t)})$ for $t>0$.

To find $<t_n>$,we proceed as follows:

Given $n$,choose $u$ with $0<u<x(\frac{1}{n})$ such that $\sin(\frac{1}{u})=(-1)^n$.

Since,$x(t)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.So, by intermediate value theorem there exists $t_n\in (0,\frac{1}{n})$ such that $x(t_n)=u$ i.e.,$\sin(\frac{1}{u})=\sin(\frac{1}{x(t_n)})=y(t_n)=(-1)^n.$**({4})**

**query from the above proof-**

> (2) How can a single point "b" be mapped to $0\times [-1,1]$?

Reference:Topology by J.R.Munkres(2nd ed.)

Comment: Post full question instead of a link.

Comment: @freakish:I tried to put whole question,but it is against MSE policies  as it comes under "duplication".

Comment: You need to ask the question *here*, in *this question*, in order to get an answer

Comment: @dbx:see the edit..

Comment: You realize $b$ is mapped *into*, not *onto*, the set $0\times [-1,1]$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can a single point "b" be mapped to $0\times [-1,1]$?

This certainly is not what the author meant. What he wanted to say is simply $f(b)\in \{0\}\times [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts:

1. Small typo: $\{ 0 \}$ and $[0,1]$ are not subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$.
2. $K$ does not have a largest element. It is a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$, which doesn't have a standard ordering on it. I think you're looking for a largest $t$ such that $f(t) \in K$. But such a thing may also not exist, you should instead be thinking about the supremum / least upper bound.
3. To answer your main question: the image of $\bf b$ isn't the whole set $K$; the wording $\bf f$ is mapped *into* $K$ is important here. It just means that $f({\bf b})\in K$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: :Agreeing with your first point.Partially agreeing with your first point.If K is closed then why not K has the largest limit point?

Comment: :In relation with your 3rd point.Since, $K\subset [a,c](domain)$.So, NO notion of K being the image of any point arises here...

Comment: I didn't say there wasn't a greatest value, just that there may not be one. Looks like I misunderstood what you were calling $K$, sorry about that. Will edit later